# Do suspended VMs on VMware Fusion impact performance on the base computer?

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine

Just trying to understand how everything works together. Sorry if this isn't the forum for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a serverfault question.

But there is no real impact besides whatever disk space is used.  When a VM is suspended, the current state gets written to the disk. After that the VM is just another directory with files in it.

Comment: Thanks. so what happens to the cores?

Comment: [Here's](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_learning_files_in_a_vm.html) a description of what files make up a VMware virtual machine.